# Solving Poisson's equation for a point charge in 1-D

Tags: fourier-analysis, poissons-equation

I Apologize that this is a continuation of a question that I just asked. Anyway here is where I am:

Ok so I was trying to solve the Poisson's equation for a point charge with a Fourier transform to get the familiar equation.

This is what I did so far:

So ultimately I am trying to solve this in 3 dimensions but I am embarrassingly struggling with the 1-D solution right now.

$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}   f(x) = \rho(x) $

I express f and ρ in terms of their Fourier transforms:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk$

and

$\rho(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}} dk$

So from here I bring the derivative into the integral that is $f(x)$ and operate on the $e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}$ term:

$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}   f(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -k^{2} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk$

I have:

$\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -k^{2} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}} dk$

And I am able to drop the integrals because the Fourier transform is unique.

$-k^{2}f(\vec{k}) = \rho(\vec{k})$

So Now I can solve for $f(x)$:

$f(\vec{k}) = \frac{\rho(\vec{k})}{-k^2}$

So now for a point charge I know that $\rho(x) = q \delta(x)$ which will leave me with the following result when i try to use Fourier transforms to transform $f(\vec{k})$ back to $f(\vec{x})$:

$f(\vec{x}) = \frac{-1}{2 \pi} \frac{q}{\epsilon_o} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk $

However I do not know how to integrate this to find the answer back in x-space. Have I went wrong somewhere or is their a certain trick to this integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We note here that all of the ensuing analysis uses notation that is interpreted in the sense of [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) or [Generalized Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function).

With that note, let's begin by breaking the problem down into components, each of which is hopefully elementary.

---

**STEP 1:**

First, we know that the Fourier Transform of the Dirac Delta $\delta$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{\delta\}(k)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{align}$$

> **ASIDE:**
>
> This implies that the Inverse Fourier Transform of the constant function $1$ is the Dirac Delta $\delta(x)$.  We can rewrite this relationship as 
>   $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}\,dk=2\pi\,\delta(x)} \tag 1$$
>   where again the notation in $(1)$ is interpreted as a distribution.

---

**STEP 2:**

Second, recall that the Fourier Transform has the property such that the Fourier Transform of the $n$'th order derivative, $D^nf$, of a function $f$, is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\mathscr{F}\{D^nf\}(k)=(ik)^n\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)} \tag 2$$

---

**STEP 3:**

Now, define the ramp function $r(x)$ as

$$r(x)=
\begin{cases}
x&,x\ge 0\\\\
0&,x<0
\end{cases}$$

Note that the second derivative of the ramp function is $D^2r=\delta$.  Using $(2)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{r\}(k)&=\frac{1}{(ik)^2}\mathscr{F}\{D^2r\}(k)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{(ik)^2}
\end{align} \tag 3$$

---

**STEP 4:**

Taking the inverse Fourier Transform of $(3)$ and multiplying by $2\pi$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\pi\,r(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{k^2}e^{-ikx}\,dk }\tag 4$$

---

**STEP 5:**

Finally, using $(4)$ we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{-1}{2\pi}\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}e^{ikx}\,dk=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}r(x)}$$

---

We can use the preceding analysis to solve the more general one-dimensional Poisson Equation

$$f''(x)=\rho(x)$$

Taking Fourier Transforms yields

$$\hat f(k)=\frac{-1}{k^2}\hat \rho(k)$$

whereupon inversion reveals that

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{k^2}\hat \rho(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{k^2} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\right)e^{-ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x')\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{k^2}e^{-ik(x-x')}\,dk\,dx'\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x')r(x-x')\,dx'\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-x')\,\rho(x')\,dx'\\\\
\end{align}$$

Thus, the general solution is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-x')\,\rho(x')\,dx'}$$

Comment: This presentation is book quality. The delta function is a magical little feature and is a transforms best friend.

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks as always!!!!  The Dirac Delta is awesome.  Did you know that Dirac's undergraduate degree was in Electrical Engineering.  I wonder when he began first thinking about the Delta.  Perhaps it was as an impulse to a circuits problem.

Comment: That I did not. I recall that there was a historical presentation in his first edition quantum mechanics book. I'm sure somewhere it goes back to Heaviside and Laplace.

Comment: @Leucippus You are correct!  Dirac coined the term in his seminal 1930 book.From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History) , it appears that it was not until Schwartz's work in 1945 that led to the formal development.