# Integral Unit Impulse Function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am having trouble integrating the following unit impulse function.

$$\int_{0}^{4} \delta(t - \tau)  \, d\tau$$

I got the answer $$u(t-4) - u(t)$$

but my professor says its $$u(t) - u(t-4)$$

Can some one clarify this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $u (t)$? It does not appear in the integrand under question. Or should the impulse function be $\int_0^4 \delta (t-\tau) u (\tau) d \tau$?

Comment: u(t) is the unit step function

Comment: Our answers could be better if you show how you reach your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the function
$$
f(\tau)=u(\tau)-u(\tau-4)
=
\begin{cases}
1 & 0<\tau<4\\
0 & \tau<0\text{ or }\tau>4.
\end{cases}
$$
(One way of seeing the second equality is that $u(\tau)$ is zero for $\tau<0$ and one for $t>0$, and $u(\tau-4)$ is zero for $\tau<4$ and one for $\tau>4$. Thus subtracting them, $u(\tau)-u(\tau-4)$ becomes what I wrote above.)

This means that your integral can be written
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\bigl(u(\tau)-u(\tau-4)\bigr)\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=(f*\delta)(t)=f(t)=u(t)-u(t-4).
$$
Here we have seen the integral as a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), and used the fact that $\delta$ acts as a unit when it comes to convolutions, i.e. $f*\delta=f$.

**Edit**

If you prefer, the derivative of $u$ is $\delta$, and hence (this is what it has to be)
$$
\int_0^4\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\bigl[-u(t-\tau)\bigr]_{\tau=0}^{4}=-u(t-4)+u(t)=u(t)-u(t-4).
$$

Comment: And this is actually the meaning of the functional $\int_0^4 \delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau$!  +1

Answer (score 0):

In [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826), I provided a primer on The Dirac Delta.  The Dirac Delta is not a function.  It is a [Generalized Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) or [Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function).

The "symbol," $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)\,\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau$, is not an integral, although it does share certain properties with the integral.  It is, rather, a linear functional that maps a test function $f$ into the number $f(t)$.

Now, the meaning of the "symbol," $\int_a^b f(\tau)\,\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau$, is the linear functional that maps the test function $f(u_a-u_b)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(\tau)\,\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)\left(u(\tau-a)-u(\tau-b)\right)\,\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=f(t)\left(u(t-a)-u(t-b)\right)
\end{align}$$

where $u$ is the unit step function defined by

$$u(t)=
\begin{cases}
1&,t>0\\\\
1/2&,t=0\\\\
0&,t<0
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, for $f(t)=1$, $a=0$, and $b=4$ we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^4 \delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=u(t)-u(t-4)}$$

as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Your error is that you have used the ''primitive'' of $\delta(t-\tau)$ with respect to $t$, that is $u(t-\tau)$ but the integral is respect to $\tau$ and the ''primitive'' is $-u(t-\tau)$.