# $\int_0^1 \lfloor -x\rfloor \,dx$

Tags: integration

Find:
$$\int_0^1 \lfloor -x\rfloor \,dx$$

I tried solving the question but got stuck along the way.  Here, as usual, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the floor function, and in my solving, I treated the negative symbol like usual. Is it wrong? Then how to calculate this problem? Help me thank you.

Comment: If $x=.5,[-x]=?$

Comment: What does "like usual" mean?

Comment: @PeterForeman Definitely not.

Comment: Note:  I have reformatted the post to use the standard notation, $\lfloor x\rfloor$, for the floor function.  If you preferred to do it the other way, you can roll back or modify  the edit.

Comment: This can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1980521/669687.

Answer (score 4):

On the open interval $(0,1)$ your function becomes $-1$. So this problem is equivalent to solving $\int_0^1 -1 \;\text{d}x$

Comment: Is it continous in [0,1)?

Comment: @F1166 No, the function is $0$ at $0$.

Comment: @F1166 you can ignore finitely many discontinuities anyway.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ecaxtly

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about this integral is to consider the form

$$\int_{-n}^0 \lfloor x\rfloor \ dx$$

which can be visualized by the step function

[image]

The area underneath this function from $-x$ to $0$ is

$$ -x -(x+1) -(x+2) - \dots  -3  -2  -1 $$

Now, since

$$\int_{-n}^0 \lfloor x\rfloor \ dx = \int_{0}^n \lfloor -x\rfloor \ dx$$

and

$$\int_{-n}^0 \lfloor x\rfloor \ dx = \sum_{k=1}^n (-k)=-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$

We see that

$$\int_{-1}^0 \lfloor x\rfloor \ dx = -\frac{1}{2}(2) = -1 = \int_{0}^1 \lfloor -x\rfloor \ dx$$