# Prove that Definite Integral of Function of Cos (t) is Larger than Definite Integral of same Function multiplied by Sin (t)

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

Can you please clarify how to prove this?

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^{k}\operatorname{d}t>\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^{k}\sin t\operatorname{d}t$$

Here, $k=1,2,3,...$

This is from Section 4.24 in Rudin Real and Complex Analysis. This inequality is part of the proof to show that there is a trigonometric Polynomial approximation for all continuous complex periodic functions.

My question is about showing that the condition is greater than ">" as opposed to ">=".

I am able to plot these functions and sort of intuitively see this as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I am confused because the question title shows a fslactor of $\cos x$ (or $\cos t$) in the greater quantity, but that factor does not appear in the question  body. Please clarify/correct.

Comment: Why not $1>\sin x>0 \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right)^k > \left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right)^k \sin x > 0$?

Comment: But sin $x = 0$ and sin $x = 1$ within the interval of integration right?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Please note I have corrected it to be "t" instead of "x". Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that if $f$ is continous on $[a,b]$ then the integral of f on the *open interval* $]a,b[$ have the same value of the integral on the *closed interval* $[a,b]$.You can see the the proof on this link [Integrating on open vs. closed intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980485/integrating-on-open-vs-closed-intervals) .Regarding your question , $\forall x \in(0,\pi)$ , $0<sinx<1$, and $1+\cos(x)>0$ , so $\forall x \in(0,\pi),$ $(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2})^k>(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2})^k$$\sin(x)$ then $\int_{0}^{\pi}(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2})^kdx>\int_{0}^{\pi}(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2})^k\ sinxdx$

Comment: Linking the related proof from this question about integration on open and closed intervals: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980485/integrating-on-open-vs-closed-intervals

Comment: @texmex Thanks for the warning, I will post it