# Delta function singularity

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, singularity

I am reading the Wiki article about [singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) and I was wondering what kind of singularity is the Dirac delta function not defined as a distribution but as this way:

\begin{equation}
\delta^{\epsilon}(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}& \hspace{30pt}\text{if} \hspace{10pt}& -\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} <x<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \\
\\
0 &\hspace{30pt} \text{if} \hspace{10pt}& |x|>\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

With $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. I would say that is an infinite discontinuity but I'm not sure.

Supposing that is an infinite discontinuity, how can I differentiate it with the singularity produced in $x=0$ by a function like:

$$
f(x)=1/x
$$

**Question:** What is the main difference between these two singularities?

Comment: for one, $\delta$ is not actually a function (it's what is called a distribution)! where as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is

Comment: A big difference is that $\delta^{\epsilon}(x)$ is integrable across $0$ and so the suggestion is that  $\delta(x)$ is too and gives a step function, while this might not be the case with $f(x)=\frac1x$

Comment: Did you mean $-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<x<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ versus $\frac{\epsilon}{2}<x<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$? If so, this is the boxcar function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) and a slight variation on the rectangle function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function).

Comment: Yes, I mean $-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<x<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Edited! But in this case $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Comment: That wikipedia article is about singularities of functions.  Not about weird non-functions like this.

Comment: The $\delta$ distribution is not a function, and the family of functions $\delta^\epsilon$ you defined doesn't converge to anything when $\epsilon\to 0$. That is, when you do $\epsilon\to 0$ you don't get a function. In both cases, you cannot apply the concepts like "infinite discontinuity" because that is defined for functions only. Do you mean to analyse these objects as distributions? In that case you should talk about singularities of distributions, but I don't know if there is a classification for these.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz. On any compact subset every distribution is a derivative of some order of a continuous function. For example, $\operatorname{pv}\frac1x$ is the second derivative of $x(\ln|x|-1).$ This can probably be used for classification.

Comment: There are ways to measure how singular a distribution at a point. First there is the wave front set which tells you in what directions the distribution is singular https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wavefront+set There is also the Steinmann scaling degree https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scaling+degree+of+a+distribution

Comment: See the primer on distributions, including the Dirac Delta and its derivative, in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826).