# How to show that $\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{a})=\lim_{\alpha\to0} \frac{\alpha/\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec{x}-\vec{a}|^2)^2}$

Tags: limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I hope to show that:
$$\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{a})=\lim_{\alpha\to0} \frac{\alpha/\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec{x}-\vec{a}|^2)^2}$$

I want to show by:
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(\vec{x}) \lim_{\alpha\to0} \frac{\alpha/\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec{x}-\vec{a}|^2)^2}\, d\vec{x}=f(\vec{a})$$
$$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(\vec{x})  \frac{\alpha/\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec{x}-\vec{a}|^2)^2}\, d\vec{x}=f(\vec{a})$$

But I do not know how to proceed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335591/divergence-of-vecf-frac-hat-mathrmrr2/1335781#1335781), I provided a rigorous development to show that the Dirac Delta can be regularized as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{a\to 0} \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r;a)=4\pi \delta(\vec r)}$$

where

$$\vec \psi(\vec r;a)=\frac{\vec r}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}} $$

Here, we will use a formal approach that can easily be made rigorous as in the aforementioned post.

---

The interpretation of the regularization of the Dirac Delta given by

$$\delta(\vec r-\vec a)\sim \lim_{\alpha \to 0}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}$$

is that for any smooth test function $f(\vec r)$, we have

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV=f(\vec a)$$

We split the integral into the sum of two integrals

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV&=\int_{\mathscr{R}^3-B_{\vec a}(\delta)}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV\\\\
&+\int_{B_{\vec a}(\delta)}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV
\end{align}$$

where $B_{\vec a}$ is a sphere of radius $\delta$ centered at $\vec a$.  Note that as $\alpha \to 0$, the first integral vanishes.  Heuristically, for small  $\delta$, the second integral can be approximated by exploiting the continuity of $f$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV&=f(\vec a)\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\int_{B_{\vec a}(\delta)}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,dV\\\\
&=f(\vec a)\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\frac{\alpha}{\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\delta}\frac{1}{(\alpha^2+r^2)^2}r^2\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=f(\vec a)\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi^2}\,(2\pi)\,(2)\,\frac{\pi}{4\alpha}\right)\\\\
&=f(\vec a)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Therefore, we have for any smooth test function $f(\vec r)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{\alpha \to 0}\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}\,f(\vec r)\,dV=f(\vec a)}$$

and it is in this sense that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\delta(\vec r-\vec a)\sim \lim_{\alpha \to 0}\frac{\alpha /\pi^2}{(\alpha^2+|\vec r-\vec a|^2)^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. How do you evaluate the last integral to obtain $\frac{\pi}{4\alpha}$?

Comment: @tony1 You're welcome.  My pleasure. The integrand is a rational function and therefore has a useful antiderivative.  One can use a trigonometric substitution to facilitate.  Note further, that one can extend the upper limit to $\infty$ since the integral from $\delta$ to $\infty$ vanishes as $\alpha \to 0$.  - Mark