# Confusion regarding the solution to $\nabla ^2 \phi(\textbf{r}) = \rho(\textbf{r})$ using Green's function

Tags: greens-function, greens-theorem

We know we can solve one of the Maxwell's equation using Green's function. More specifically, we can solve

$$\nabla ^2 \phi(\textbf{r}) = \rho(\textbf{r})$$

using
$$\phi(\textbf{r}) = \int d\textbf{r}' G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') \rho(\textbf{r})
\qquad\text{where}\qquad
\nabla ^2 G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') = \delta (\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'),$$
and
$$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')=\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}$$ follows.

However, I cannot understand how we obtain the delta function $\delta (\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}')$ by having the Laplacian act on $G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')$. Any thoughts on how can I obtain that?

Comment: You would need to be careful and deal with distributions. The idea is do the integral on all of space with a little ball cut out at the origin, then use integration by parts and show that the limit as the radius of the ball goes to zero is $4\pi \rho(0)$ (with the function $\frac{1}{|r|}$ that is )

Comment: @LL3.14 [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335591/divergence-of-vecf-frac-hat-mathrmrr2/1335781#1335781), which I posted in June 2015, might be of interest also.

Comment: Here's a calculation I had made earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2415552/168433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REGULARIZING THE DIRAC DELTA:**

As I showed in [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335591/divergence-of-vecf-frac-hat-mathrmrr2/1335781#1335781), we can show that $\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\right)=4\pi \delta (\vec r)$ by using a regularization of the Dirac Delta.  To begin, let $\vec \psi$ be the function given by

$$\vec \psi(\vec r;a)=\frac{\vec r}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \tag 1$$

where we note that $\psi(\vec r;0)=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ for $\vec r\ne0$.

The divergence of $(1)$ is

$$\nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)=\frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}$$

And as shown in the referenced answer, for any test function $\phi$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r; a)\phi(\vec r)\,dV=\begin{cases}4\pi \phi(0)&, \{0\}\in V\\\\
0&,\{0\}\notin V
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

and it is in this sense that

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r;a)\sim 4\pi \delta(\vec r)$$

Enforcing the translation $\vec r\mapsto \vec r-\vec r'$ yields the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{a\to 0} \nabla \cdot \vec \psi(\vec r-\vec r';a)\sim 4\pi \delta(\vec r-\vec r')}$$

---

---

**CLASSICAL ANALYSIS:**

> **We need not use the Dirac Delta to prove that $\nabla^2\int_{V}\rho(\vec r')G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'=\rho(\vec r)$.**

For $\rho(\vec r)\in C^\infty_C$ the gradient of $\phi(\vec r)$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \int_{V}\rho(\vec r')G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'&=\int_{V}\rho(\vec r')\nabla G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'\\\\
&=-\int_{V}\rho(\vec r')\nabla' G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'\\\\
&=-\oint_{\partial V}\rho(\vec r') G(\vec r,\vec r')\hat n'\,dS'+\int_{V}\nabla' \rho(\vec r')G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'\tag2
\end{align}$$

Taking the divergence of $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \int_{V}\rho(\vec r')G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'&=\oint_{\partial V}\rho(\vec r') \frac{\partial G(\vec r,\vec r')}{\partial n'}\,dS'-\int_{V}\nabla' \rho(\vec r')\cdot \nabla 'G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'\tag3
\end{align}$$

We may write the integrand of the integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\nabla' \rho(\vec r')\cdot \nabla 'G(\vec r,\vec r')=\nabla' \cdot (\rho(\vec r')\nabla' G(\vec r,\vec r'))-\rho(\vec r')\nabla'^2 G(\vec r,\vec r')$$

but cannot apply the Divergence Theorem since $\nabla'G(\vec r,\vec r')$is not continuously differentiable in $V$.  We can work around this issue by proceeding as follows.

We exclude the singularity at $\vec r'=\vec r$ from $V$ with a spherical volume $V_\varepsilon$ with center at $\vec r$ and with radius $\varepsilon$.  Then, using $\nabla'^2 G(\vec r,\vec r')=0$ for $\vec r'\in V-V\varepsilon$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{V}\nabla' \rho(\vec r')\cdot \nabla 'G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{V-V_\varepsilon}\nabla' \rho(\vec r')\cdot \nabla 'G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial V+\partial V_\epsilon}\rho(\vec r') \frac{\partial G(\vec r,\vec r')}{\partial n'}\,dS'\\\\
&=\int_{\partial V}\rho(\vec r') \frac{\partial G(\vec r,\vec r')}{\partial n'}\,dS'\\\\
&+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \rho(\vec r')\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{\varepsilon^3}\cdot \frac{\vec r'-\vec r}{\varepsilon}\,\varepsilon^2\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_{\partial V}\rho(\vec r') \frac{\partial G(\vec r,\vec r')}{\partial n'}\,dS'-4\pi \rho(\vec r)\tag4
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(4)$ into $(3)$, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\nabla^2 \int_{V}\rho(\vec r')G(\vec r,\vec r')\,dV'=4\pi \rho(\vec r)}\tag5$$

---

---

Inasmuch as $(5)$ is true for any test function $\rho(\vec r)$, we see that in the sense of distributions

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\nabla^2 G(\vec r,\vec r')=4\pi \delta(\vec r-\vec r')}$$

Answer (score 2):

Define a vector field
$$
\mathbf{F} 
= \nabla \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|}
= -\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}
.
$$

If we take the divergence of this, we see that it vanishes:
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}
= - \frac{(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{r})|\mathbf{r}|^3 - \mathbf{r}\cdot3|\mathbf{r}|^2\mathbf{r}/|\mathbf{r}|}{|\mathbf{r}|^6}
= -\frac{3|\mathbf{r}|-3|\mathbf{r}|^3}{|\mathbf{r}|^6}
= 0.
$$
But this calculation is only defined for $\mathbf{r} \neq \mathbf{0}.$ To cover origin we will use the divergence theorem:
$$
\iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot\mathbf{F} \, dV = \iint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS,
$$
where $\Omega$ is some region with a smooth enough boundary $\partial\Omega.$ If $\Omega$ does not contain origin, both sides of the equality vanish. Now take $\Omega=B_r(\mathbf{0}),$ i.e. a ball with radius $r$ and center in origin. Then $\partial\Omega$ is the sphere $S_r(\mathbf{0})$ with radius $r$ and center in origin, and the right hand side becomes
$$
\iint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS
= \iint_{S_r(\mathbf{0})} \left(-\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}\right)\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|} \,|\mathbf{r}|^2 d\omega
= -\iint_{S_r(\mathbf{0})} d\omega
= -4\pi
.
$$
(Here $\omega$ is the [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) measure.)

Thus,
$$
\iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot\mathbf{F} \, dV
= \begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } \mathbf{0} \not\in \Omega \\
-4\pi, & \text{ if } \mathbf{0} \in \Omega \\
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = -4\pi\,\delta(\mathbf{r}).$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please comment whether or not we can establish a relation for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} F_x = \frac{1}{3} \delta(\textbf{r})$ or something like that?

Comment: Quick follow-up question, what happened to the minus sign?

Comment: @denis. The minus sign was stolen. Now I have got it back, thanks to the math police. ;-)

Comment: thanks! @md2perpe
Do you know whether we could affirm anything related to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F_x = \frac{1}{3} \delta(\textbf{r})$ ?

Comment: @denis. That formula hardly is valid. It should have some derivative of $\delta.$

Comment: I'm sorry @md2perpe, I meant $\frac{d}{dx} F_x = \frac{1}{3} \delta(\textbf{r})$.

Comment: @md2perpe When I was a professor (1000 years ago) and teaching electromagnetic field theory, I used your approach.  It's fast and does yield the correct result.  But I know that you know that the Divergence Theorem is really inapplicable for $\vec F=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ and $\Omega =B_r(0)$. So, I've posted a solution with two approaches.  The first uses a regularization of the Dirac Delta and the second uses classical analysis.  As always, I enjoy our conversations and would like to hear from you.

Comment: @MarkViola. The divergence theorem is inapplicable but if $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\operatorname{sing supp}\vec{F} \cap \Omega = \emptyset$ then $\iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS$ is defined and one can even define $\vec{F}\chi_\Omega$ as a distribution. Take $\rho\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\rho\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $\Omega$. Then $\langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle = \iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS.$ Abusing integral notation we can write $\langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle$ as $\iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot\vec{F} \, dV.$

Comment: Computation:
$$
0 
= -\langle \vec{F}\chi_\Omega \stackrel{\bullet}{,} \nabla\rho \rangle
= \langle \nabla\cdot(\vec{F}\chi_\Omega), \rho \rangle
= \langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle + \langle \vec{F}\cdot\nabla\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle \\
= \langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle - \iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS
.
$$

Comment: @md2perpe Even easier.  Define the distribution $D_{\vec F}$ as $\langle \vec F, \phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^3 \vec F\phi \,dV$, since $\vec F=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ is integrable locally.   Then using linearity and the definition of the distributional derivative, we have $$\langle \nabla \cdot \vec F, \phi\rangle=-\sum_{i}\langle F_i,\partial_i  \phi\rangle =-\int_V \vec F\cdot \nabla \phi\,dV$$Now, we follow the development in $(4)$ of my posted solution and we are done.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola. Well, that's the definition of $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$. What I wanted to show was a distributional form of the divergence theorem.

Comment: I think I just showed that.  Once we get to $-\int_V \nabla \phi \cdot \vec F\,dV$ we are into purely classical analysis since $\vec F$ is locally integrable.

Comment: @MarkViola. Yes, but with your approach you don't define $\iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot\vec{F} \, dV$ or $\iint_{\partial\Omega} \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n} \, dS.$ (I see now that I missed index ${}_{\partial\Omega}$ on the double integral in my computation.

Comment: I define the distribution $\nabla \cdot \vec F$ which operates on test functions.  Since the distribution itself has compact support $\{0\}$, then it's easy to define how it operates on $1$.

Comment: @MarkViola. I this case $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ has compact support, but what I do is more general. I don't require compact support of $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$.

Comment: @MarkViola. You might think that I define $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ in some complicated way, but I don't. I define it in the same way as you do. What I do is to show a distributional version of the divergence theorem, and this justifies the calculations I made in my post.

Comment: @md2perpe I do understand.  Basically, the distribution transfers to $\nabla \chi_\Omega$, which is a Dirac Delta itself.  The approach is fine.

Comment: @MarkViola. $\nabla\chi_\Omega$ is a vector distribution supported on the boundary of $\Omega$. It's basically $-\iint \cdots \vec{n}\,dS.$

Comment: Yes, I know what the object is:  $\langle \nabla \chi_\Omega,\phi\rangle =\oint_S \phi(r,\theta,\phi) \,\hat r\,r^2 \,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi$So, if $\phi=1$ we have $\langle \vec F\cdot  \nabla\chi_\Omega,\phi\rangle=4\pi$